# What are the advantages and disadvantages of Eryone's 15% metal PLA compared to other PLA?

Tags: creality-ender-3, pla, material

I am thinking of using it for a project or two but am still somewhat new to this.

So, I was wondering what are the advantages and disadvantages of Eryone's 15% metal PLA and X% metal PLA in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advantage: It should print like regular PLA at PLA temperatures.

Disadvantage: the embedded metal particles are abrasive and will widen your standard brass nozzle over time.  The fix is to use a hardened steel nozzle, or for the extreme, there are options like ruby-tipped nozzles.

Advantage: It should look "metallic" in a way that is more durable than a paint-on topcoat finish, with a depth instead of a surface-only appearance.

Disadvantage: I can't find the product you're referencing.  The nearest I can find is [**Metal Silk Rainbow PLA**](https://x3d.com.au/collections/eryone/products/shiny-silk-metal-rainbow-pla-1-75mm)  and [**Ultra Silk PLA**](https://eryone3d.com/products/advanced-silk-pla)

That latter one is available in gold, bronze, copper, silver, etc. which sounds like metal, but only printing some will show you in person what it looks like.

---

See also [Additional mods for printing metal filled filament with Ender 3 V2?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/14239/additional-mods-for-printing-metal-filled-filament-with-ender-3-v2)

Comment: @agarza  "Embiggen" is a perfectly cromulent word.

Comment: That's fine, but the idea is for users to easily understand what the answer is. I would venture to say that a great number of people will not know the definition of "embiggen" unless they look it up, which they won't because they are too lazy.

Comment: thanks that's just the answer I needed, also @agarza is right I didn't even know that word existed until now.